# object literal with arrays brackets positioning

Tags: javascript

I made this object literal and I don't understand what is the right brackets positioning for the array that comes after `active`. Why am I getting missing brackets error?

```
    var players = {
            player1 : {
                active : true,
                [
                    {
                        row : 1,
                        square : 1
                    },{
                        row : 2,
                        square : 1
                    },{
                        row : 3,
                        square : 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
```

Comment: `active` is a key in a dictionary. The array must get a key too.

Comment: That isn't JSON. It is a JavaScript object literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, that's not [JSON](http://json.org), that's a [JavaScript object initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) (sometimes called an "object literal").

The problem is the `[` here:

```
active: true,
[
```

You need a key before that value. The basic form is `key: value`, where the key is the name of the property (can be an identifier, a number, or a string in JavaScript; in JSON it would have to be a string, and in double quotes not single quotes) and the value is, well, the value. :-)

Comment: thanx, why is that not JSON?

Comment: @IlyaD: Because it's source code, not data text, and also it's not in the format dictated by JSON. JSON is a textual data notation. If you're writing JavaScript source code, you're writing JavaScript object initializers. JSON is a subset of object initializer syntax, used for data, not code. One random difference: In JSON, the property names (keys) must be in double quotes. In JavaScript, they need not be. Another random difference: JavaScript supports `undefined` as a value, JSON does not. JSON supports string literals only if they're in double quotes, JavaScript supports single quotes too.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In JSON, all the keys must be in double quotes?

Comment: @IlyaD: *(This replaces my comment in January, which was slightly incorrect.)* Yup, see the link in the answer. But since what you're doing there isn't JSON, they're optional, you only need quotes around property names if they're not valid identifier names. For instance, the property name `1st`: Since it's not a valid identifier name (it starts with a digit), you can't do `{1st: "foo"}` but you can do `{"1st": "foo"}` or `{'1st': "foo"}`. In JSON, only `{"1st": "foo"}` is valid. In JavaScript, the keys can also be numeric literals, such as `{0: "zero", 1: "one"}`. Not so JSON.

Answer (score 4):

The value of the `active` property can be either the boolean `true` or an array. It can't be both.

You need to change it to either:

```
active : [ ... ]
```

or

```
active : true,
somethingElse : [ ... ]
```

or some other valid data structure.

Answer (score 0):

active is set to 2 values, `true` and your array. To test your JSON, use http://jsonlint.com/.